# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function while trying to run react-native-web project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-web

I have cloned my native project and trying o run it on web but as soon as I add the below lines

```
 const {navigation} = props;
  const childId = props.route.params.childId;
  const diet = props.route.params.diet;
  const [selectedDiet, setSelectedDiet] = useState(diet.options);
  const cuisines = props.route.params.cuisines;
  const date = new Date();
```

after my return I get the following error:

[image]

could anyone please help me out here,
I have installed prettier-eslint, but that did not help
below I would add m entire code just for some more clarity,

```
     import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import qs from 'qs';
import {Images} from '../../assets';
import {API} from '../../api';
import {disabledColor, successColor} from '../../config/colors';

export default function LoginScreenWeb(props) {
  const {navigation} = props;
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');
  const [width, getWidth] = useState(null);
  const SetWidth = () => {
    getWidth(window.screen.availWidth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    SetWidth();
    setInterval(SetWidth, 1000);
  }, []);

  const onHandlePress = () => {
    async function post() {
      try {
        const response = await API.postFormData(
          `/users/signup`,
          qs.stringify({
            firstName,
            mobile,
          }),
        );
        navigation.navigate('otp');
        localStorage.setItem('mobile', mobile);
        console.log('loginRes--', response);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    post();
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={
          width > 414 ? styles.inner_container_web : styles.inner_container_mob
        }>
        <Image
          source={Images.login_web}
          style={width > 414 ? styles.image_web : styles.image_mob}
        />
        <KeyboardAvoidingView>
          <View style={{padding: 16}}>
            <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Name</Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Enter your name"
              style={styles.textInput}
              value={firstName}
              onChangeText={(firstName) =>
                setFirstName(firstName.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''))
              }
            />
            <Text style={styles.textLabel}>+91</Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Enter your phone number"
              style={styles.textInput}
              maxLength={10}
              keyboardType="number-pad"
              value={mobile}
              onChangeText={(mobile) =>
                setMobile(mobile.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))
              }
            />
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
              {firstName && mobile.length === 10 ? (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => onHandlePress()}
                  style={styles.enable_continue}>
                  <Text style={styles.continue}>Continue</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.disble_continue}>
                  <Text style={styles.continue}>Continue</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <View style={styles.cookies} />
              <Text style={{fontSize: '12px'}}>
                By continuing you agree to the Terms of Service and Privacy
                policy
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5',
  },
  inner_container_web: {
    width: '600px',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: '578px',
  },
  inner_container_mob: {
    width: '359px',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  image_web: {
    width: '600px',
    height: '279px',
  },
  image_mob: {
    width: '360px',
    height: '200px',
  },
  textLabel: {
    fontWeight: '600',
    fontSize: '16px',
  },
  disble_continue: {
    width: '266px',
    height: '48px',
    backgroundColor: disabledColor,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: '8px',
  },
  enable_continue: {
    width: '266px',
    height: '48px',
    backgroundColor: successColor,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: '8px',
  },
  continue: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: '18px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  cookies: {
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    width: 4,
    height: 4,
    borderRadius: 2,
    marginTop: '1%',
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  textInput: {
    outline: 'none',
    borderBottomColor: disabledColor,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
};
```

[image]

It would be a great help if anyone could help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error is on a component called `LoginScreen`, but you've included the code to a different component. Can you include `LoginScreen`?

Comment: I am sorry my bad, have included Loginscreen

Comment: Have edited the questions, you could check once please @jnpdx

Comment: What version of React are you using (check package.json)?

Comment: "react": "^16.5.1" @jnpdx

Comment: Hooks aren't available until 16.8 -- neither `useState` or `useEffect` should be available until then.